# GeoPosition coordinates from Shape file (.SHP) with unknown Datum

Tags: geography, geodesy

The City of Amsterdam supports an Open Data policy. Much information can be retrieved at the level of boroughs (stadsdelen). Unfortunately, `GeoGraphics` does not provide outlines of these smaller areas. A bundle of Shape files (.SHP) of [Administrative Areas](http://maps.amsterdam.nl/open_geodata/?LANG=en) can be downloaded.

I want to overlay these areas with the city map, but the .SHP data are in a coordinate system which is not recognized. (Related to [42533](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42533/latitude-longitude-to-transverse-mercator-projection).)

Overall, the images of the administrative areas look good (no reverse coordinates)

[image: Boroughs of Amsterdam]

but the coordinates are not in geographic {Latitude,Longitude}, since Amsterdam is at

```
CityData[Entity["City",{"Amsterdam","NoordHolland","Netherlands"}],"Coordinates"]
```

gives {52.37, 4.89}.

The coordinate system

```
Import[amsterdamDir, "CoordinateSystemInformation"]
```

gives

```
"PROJCS" -> {"RD_New", 
"GEOGCS" -> {"GCS_Amersfoort", 
"DATUM" -> {"Amersfoort", 
  "SPHEROID" -> {"Bessel_1841", 6.3774*10^6, 299.153}}, 
"PRIMEM" -> {"Greenwich", 0}, 
"UNIT" -> {"Degree", 0.0174532925199432955}}, 
"PROJECTION" -> {"Double_Stereographic"}, 
"PARAMETER" -> {"False_Easting", 155000}, 
"PARAMETER" -> {"False_Northing", 463000}, 
"PARAMETER" -> {"Central_Meridian", 5.38764}, 
"PARAMETER" -> {"Scale_Factor", 0.999908}, 
"PARAMETER" -> {"Latitude_Of_Origin", 52.1562}, 
"UNIT" -> {"Meter", 1}}
```

However, its Datum (GCSAmersfoort) is unknown. (Amersfoort is another city in The Netherlands.)

How can I transform these coordinates to GeoPosition coordinates?

For testing, a tiny polygon from the Shape file is

```
Polygon[{{115050., 485415.}, {115614., 485596.}, {115601., 
485634.}, {115887., 485725.}, {116049., 485777.}, {116052., 
485768.}, {116124., 485793.}, {116136., 485798.}, {116154., 
485809.}, {116162., 485816.}, {116171., 485825.}, {116262., 
485750.}, {116263., 485687.}, {116263., 485666.}, {116236., 
485665.}, {116206., 485662.}, {116148., 485649.}, {116122., 
485642.}, {115834., 485549.}, {115846., 485509.}, {115684., 
485456.}, {115676., 485481.}, {115578., 485449.}, {115633., 
485279.}, {115564., 485257.}, {115494., 485229.}, {115211., 
485138.}, {115146., 485116.}, {115061., 485378.}, {115050., 
485415.}}]
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

Following @jose's solution I obtain this map, with the above polygon overlaid

[image]

This shows a small area (Calandlaan/Lelylaan buurt) in Amsterdam-West. A screenshot from maps of the [City of Amsterdam](http://maps.amsterdam.nl/gebiedsindeling/?z=52.290631,4.770137,52.419276,4.989863,1&klik=52.354635,4.805145&leg=1&emb=0) show this outline

[image]

The correspondence is close, but there is a small displacement to be resolved.

**EDIT 2**

The shift between the two solutions of @gwr is about 21 cm. 
Just by taking the `GeoDistance[ ]` between the two projections of the same coordinate.

```
pos1=rdPosition[{115061, 485378 },OffsetGrid->{+25.14, +116.91}, OffsetWGS84->{0, 0}]
pos2=rdPosition[{115061, 485378 },OffsetGrid->{+0, +0}, OffsetWGS84 ->{-0.001053524113977744`, -0.000352533797287613`}]

GeoDistance[{pos1,pos2}]

OUT:
GeoPosition[{52.3548, 4.80096}, "WGS84"]
GeoPosition[{52.3548, 4.80097}, "WGS84"]
Quantity[0.206247, "Meters"]
```

Indeed, too small to discern at the scale of the maps.

Comment: Here is another comparison shot showing the slight difference between the regions:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/5kL5b.jpg

Comment: Some information in general on projections from TU Delft [here](http://doris.tudelft.nl/Literature/strangvanhees06.pdf). For transportation modeling I once had a similar challenge which could be solved by [Gauss-Krüger](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5888/764) - there is a general link there to the [epsg](http://www.epsg.org/) which may be helpful. Here in Germany all cities should rather use a similar projection - should that not be rather standardized for NL as well?

Comment: For completeness [this](http://www.kadaster.nl/web/file?uuid=6e28f8e0-0bbb-4211-b5be-516022ca2fec&owner=23cbe925-35ce-4a72-ac8c-a33a0c19ae1e&contentid=5103) is the official (bilingual) description of the geodetic systems used in the Netherlands.

Comment: I thank gwr, JasonB, and jose for their time and efforts. This was more difficult than I had anticipated.

Comment: You may have noticed that my map of Amsterdam (above) has coordinates (via Frame->True) which do not match the latitude, and perhaps longitude, of the city (also above). Any suggestions?

Comment: Regarding the Frame-Coordinates given for the map you should take a look at the [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeoGraphics.html) for `GeoGraphics`. There is a section called *Projected Coordinates* which explains what is going on. If you press the right button on you mouse, the menu gives *get coordinates*. Using this feature will show you, that everything in fact is in order: lat,lon - values will match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since there is a rather constant offset between ITRF00 and WGS84 we might expand upon @jose's solution:

```
Clear[rdPosition];

rdPosition::usage = "\
rdPosition[{x,y}] takes a geocentric position according to the new \
Dutch RD system and returns a GeoPosition using WGS84";

Options[rdPosition] = {
    "OffsetWGS84" -> {0, 0}, (* {Δϕ,Δλ} to adjust ITRF00 -> WGS84 *)
    "OffsetGrid"  -> {+25.14, +116.91} (* {ΔEast,ΔNorth} to adjust GridOrigin *)
};

(* OffsetWGS84 of original answer was {-0.001053524113977744`, -0.000352533797287613`} *)

rdPosition[ pos : {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}, opts:OptionsPattern[rdPosition] ] := With[
  {
    falseEasting = 155000,
    falseNorthing = 463000,
    centering = {52.1562, 5.38764},
    centralScaleFactor = 0.999908,
    referenceEllipsoid = "Bessel1841",
    offsetGrid = OptionVAlue["OffsetGrid"],
    offsetWGS84 = OptionValue["OffsetWGS84"]
  },
  GeoGridPosition[
    pos,
    {
      "Stereographic", (* projection *)
      "ReferenceModel" -> referenceEllipsoid,
      "GridOrigin" -> {falseEasting, falseNorthing} + offsetGrid,
      "Centering" -> centering,
      "CentralScaleFactor" -> centralScaleFactor
    }
  ] // RightComposition[
         GeoPosition, (* using WL standard ITRF00 *)
         ReplaceAll[ GeoPosition[{ϕ_, λ_}] :> GeoPosition[{ϕ, λ} + offsetWGS84, "WGS84"] ]
       ]
]
```

Using the conversion tool [here](http://www.gpscoordinaten.nl/converteer-rd-coordinaten.php) we can check this function:

```
rdPosition @ {115061, 485378 }
```

> GeoPosition[{52.3548, 4.80096}, "WGS84"]

This seems *close enough* and we can now simply add a convenient function to convert shape data and use it:

```
Clear[ shapeConvert ];

shapeConvert::usage = "\
shapeConvert[data] converts the shape data to geographic primitives\
which can be used within GeoGraphics.";

shapeConvert[ shapeData_, opts:OptionsPattern[rdPosition] ] := ReplaceAll[
    shapeData,
    pos:{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> pos ~ rdPosition ~ opts
]
```

### Administrative Areas

```
amstAreas = ReplaceAll[
    "Geometry", 
    Import[
      "http://maps.amsterdam.nl/gebiedsindeling/GEBIEDSINDELINGEN.ZIP",
      {"SHP", "Data"}
    ]
];

Row[{
  amstAreas[[-2, 1]] // shapeConvert[ #, 
      OffsetGrid -> {+25.14, +116.91}, 
      OffsetWGS84 -> {0, 0}
  ] & // GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Red], #}, ImageSize -> Large] & ,
  amstAreas[[-2, 1]] // shapeConvert[#, 
      OffsetGrid -> {+0, +0}, 
      OffsetWGS84 -> {-0.001053524113977744`, -0.000352533797287613`}
  ] & // GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Orange], #}, ImageSize -> Large] &
}]
```

[image: Amsterdam1]

```
Row[{
  amstAreas[[2, 1]] // shapeConvert[ #, 
      OffsetGrid -> {+25.14, +116.91}, 
      OffsetWGS84 -> {0, 0}
  ] & // GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Red], #}, ImageSize -> Large] & ,
  amstAreas[[2, 1]] // shapeConvert[#, 
      OffsetGrid -> {+0, +0}, 
      OffsetWGS84 -> {-0.001053524113977744`, -0.000352533797287613`}
  ] & // GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Orange], #}, ImageSize -> Large] &
}]
```

[image: Amsterdam2]

I fail to really spot a difference between using a Grid-Offset and a WGS84-Offset.

### Update

I have now implemented two different possible offsets (Grid, WGS84) by using options to `rdPosition`. The options may also be passed to `shapeConvert`. The grid offset has been proposed by @jose in a comment to his answer.

Comment: The parameter `offsetWGS84` was of course derived using the conversion tool cited in my answer. One might try more data points but I found that it seems reasonably close.

Comment: this looks impressive!

Comment: I have now implemented options as to allow Grid- and LatLon-Offsets as suggested by @jose. The differences remain invisible to my eye though.

Comment: Please see my Edit 2.

Answer (score 9):

I'm still hoping that jose might be able to make this work using `GeoGridPosition` or `GeoGridPositionXYZ`. Or maybe some ambitious person will use the equations on page 65 of [this pdf](http://www.iogp.org/pubs/373-07-2.pdf) to do the job manually.

But I'm just going to farm the job out to the [PROJ.4 Cartographic Projections Library](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/wiki), which I installed by following the instructions [here](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2015/10/05/mac-os-x-installing-the-proj-4-cartographic-projections-library/).

In this function, you will need to change the path to the `cs2cs` script for your local installation,

```
ClearAll[convertAmersfoort]
convertAmersfoort[data_?(ArrayQ[#, _, NumericQ] &)] := 
  Module[{cs2cs, file, result}, 
   cs2cs = "~/projects/land-registry/proj-4.9.1/bin/cs2cs";
   file = CreateTemporary[];
   Export[file, data, "Table"];
   result = 
    Import["!" <> cs2cs <> 
        " -f '%.7f' +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 \
+lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 \
+ellps=bessel \
+towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 \
+units=m +no_defs +to +proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 -s " <> file, 
       "Table"] // Map@Most // GeoPosition;
   DeleteFile[file];
   result];
convertAmersfoort[pgons_] := 
  ReplaceAll[
   pgons, {Polygon[a__] :> Polygon@convertAmersfoort@a, 
    Line[a__] :> Line@convertAmersfoort@a}];
```

If `pgon` is the polygon defined at the end of the OP, then

```
GeoGraphics[{
  EdgeForm[Directive[Blue, Thick, Dashed]], convertAmersfoort[pgon]
  }
 ]
```

returns a faithful reproduction of the linked original,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can apply this to all the polygons from the original SHP file.  Here is another example of the comparison,

```
amstAreas = 
  "Geometry" /. 
   Import["http://maps.amsterdam.nl/gebiedsindeling/GEBIEDSINDELINGEN.ZIP", {"SHP", "Data"}];
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Blue, Thick, Dashed]], 
  convertAmersfoort[amstAreas[[-2, 1]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

versus that from the original site:

[image]

If there were method for using the 7-parameter "towgs84" datum-conversion, then using another program would not be necessary.

Comment: @RomkeBontekoe - I was able to get the proper transformation.

Comment: This looks very good!

Answer (score 7):

My approximation to that projection is

```
proj = {"Stereographic", "ReferenceModel" -> "Bessel1841", "GridOrigin" -> {155000, 463000}, "Centering" -> {52.1562, 5.38764}, "CentralScaleFactor" -> 0.999908}
```

However, I don't know how to relate the Amersfoort datum to WGS84, and this may result in a global displacement.

Calling pol the testing polygon given above, try this:

```
GeoGridPosition[First[pol], proj]

geopol = Polygon[GeoPosition[%]]

GeoGraphics[geopol]
```

Does the result look reasonable?

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It is certainly close, but, as you also noted, it appears somewhat displaced. I fail to see where your WGS84 comes from.

Comment: The WL maps use lat, lon coordinates on the ITRF00 datum, which is nearly identical to WGS84. Any other datum may use an ellipsoid with different orientation or center, and that can affect the meaning of latitude and longitude. Then, separately, we need the cartographic projection to convert those lat, lon values into the x, y coordinates of the flat map. The projection specification I gave handles the second part, but assumes that there is no datum change.

Comment: Comparing with the code given by JasonB, the results coincide to a few parts per million for the test polygon, which corresponds to sub-meter precision. How large is the displacement you see, Romke?

Comment: @jose - This is great, the result is visibly indistinguishable to what I put below.  I wish there was more information on the parameters you can and can't feed to the projection argument of `GeoGridPosition`.  BTW, would there be any easier way of making that plot than using replacement rules on the `Polygon` and `FilledCurve[{{Line[...` objects?  [This is what I came up with](http://pastebin.com/raw/sKweweuC)

Comment: For example, could it be possible for something like `GeoGraphics[First@First@amstAreas, GeoProjection -> proj]` to work?

Comment: @jose - Please see my edit.

Comment: @jose Is it true, that WL cannot transfer ITRF (or some other datum) to WGS84 - which is among the most relevant geodetic systems? The information how to do it seems to be public [here](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/coordsys/csat_pubs.html) it seems. What other conversions would people be interested in? :)

Comment: The Wolfram Language knows how to transform between many pairs of datums, using 7-parameter Helmert transformations (3 parameters for a translation, 3 parameters for a rotation and 1 parameter for a global rescaling). GeodesyData knows the relevant information, and GeoPosition/GeoPositionXYZ can access it. The difference between WGS84 and ITRF00 is small, and can be ignored. However, the parameters needed here are not small, judging by the towgs84 values given by @JasonB.

Comment: @jose - is there any mechanism to provide the 7 parameters to `GeoPositionXYZ` manually, in addition to the centering, scaling, and origin values?

Comment: Using the fact that we are dealing with a small region of the world, I think the simplest solution here is to implement a constant offset as suggested by @gwr. However, I would implement a constant offset in projected space, not in latlon space. Hence, change the "GridOrigin" parameter in the projection I gave above to {155025.14, 463116.91}. This approximates the results given by JasonB.